# Use Symfony2 assetic for managing assets other than images, js and css

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

Use Symfony2 assetic for managing assets other than images, js and css. Other assets such as swf, fonts etc or to be generic is there any generic option that can be used with assetic to use just about any type of file...file.xxx

For images it's :

```
{% image '@mybundlename/Resources/public/images/sample.png' %}
<img src="{{ assets_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

For stylesheets it's :

```
{% stylesheets ......
```

For javascripts it's :

```
{% javascripts..... }
```

So like wise what about other types of files.

Comment: where's the question?

Comment: right above your comment!!

Comment: xD @RobinRizvi Don is right, you have to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

You can use twigs asset function

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Symfony!" />

<link href="{{ asset('css/blog.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you can try

```
{% image '@mybundlename/Resources/some/some.swf' %}
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ assets_url }}" /> 
{% endimage %}
```

But, if yours file located in the `Resources/public/*`, i.e. `/ExampleBundle/Resources/public/flash/some.swf` -  use:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ asset('bundles/example/flash/some.swf') }}" />
```